# Angular 2 , generate results table when parent component makes rest call

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

I want to

- Run a REST query in my parent component (**getTest()**)
- Upon running the above query I want it to populate **results: test[]** with the results
- Once **results: test[]** has been populated I want it to be passed down to the child class so that it can be used to generate a HTML table so that the rows of the table represent the results.

My problem is that the **ngOnChanges()** method in the child class never gets called so Im not sure how to get the results from the parent when they become available.

Here is my parent and child component .ts file

```
export class BlotterComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
showAdvancedForm: boolean;
results: test[];

constructor(private blotterPostService: BlotterPostService) {
    this.showAdvancedForm = false;
}

ngOnInit() {}

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    console.log("ngOnChanges BlotterComponent");
    console.log(this.results);
}

getTest() {
    console.log("Running test RESTful query..");
    this.blotterTradesPostService.getTestQuery().subscribe(u => {
        this.results = u;
        console.log(this.results);
    });
    }
}
```

Here is my child component .ts file.

```
export class TestTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() testResults: test[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
      console.log("ngOnChanges TestTableComponent search results");
      console.log(this.testResults);
  }
```

}

Comment: use *ngIf in child component .. till result not able .. If results get available then pass data to child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service and use [Event Emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to emit the changes and than subscribe to those changes in child component for that you have to

1:-Create a service

```
import { Injectable, Inject,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class EmitterService {
public testEmitter:EventEmitter<test[]>=new EventEmitter(); 
}
```

2.in your root component  inject service depandany in counstructor and emit once result comes

```
  constructor(private emitter :EmitterService) //inject service

 this.blotterTradesPostService.getTestQuery().subscribe(u => {
    this.emitter.testEmitter.emit(u);
    console.log(this.results);
});
```

3.In your child component constructor

```
  constructor(private emitter :EmitterService){
    this.emitter.testEmitter.subscribe(results =>{
    //here you can write your code it will be called every time emit method is called
  })
 }
```

For more info you can check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d42bKafINUqJ1xDQKpXo?p=preview)

Comment: @itender hi thanks for the response. Im not 100% about step 3, what actually would go inside the "//here you can write your code" ? Im assuming this emitter will be triggered for every row/result my query returns? In which can would I need to add each result to a list variable in the child class?

Comment: @JamesRelic basically you will get results in child every time you call the emit method from the parent component and there you can play accordingly

Comment: @itender I guess im not sure if this.emitter.testEmitter.subscribe(results would be return test or test[]. The blotterTradesPostService.getTestQuery() returns test[]

Comment: @JamesRelic it would return   test[] as we can only emit test[] type which we specify in  EventEmitter<test[]>

Comment: also you can give it a try and can check the results and modify accordingly